# Array and structures strange behavior

Tags: javascript, arrays, data-structures, behavior

I try to set up a quiz with several questions. Each question will use the same input fields like this:

Who was President in 1984?
1 - Carter
2 - Clinton
3 - Reagan
4 - Call a friend!

It must be something that I do not understand. Here is what happens:

I declare an array and a variable:

```
// Questions Data Structure
var qData = {};
var questionList = new Array();
var curQuestion = parseInt(0);
```

In a given form the user can enter values within various input fields and textareas.
Then user can click a "Save Answers" button before going to the next question in the same web page without postback.
The save button do this (`gel()` is a short for `document.getElementById`):

```
curQuestion++;
qData.qQuestionText = gel("questionText").value;

qData.qAnswer1 = gel("Answer1").value;
qData.qAnswer2 = gel("Answer2").value;
qData.qAnswer3 = gel("Answer3").value;
qData.qAnswer4 = gel("Answer4").value;

qData.qAnswerText = gel("AnswerText").value;
questionList[curQuestion] = qData;
```

The first question is saved OK.
Now, believe it or not, when the `qData` structure change at question 2 (or 3...), the value of ALL elements in the `questionList` array will change and they will ALL receive the same value!

It is as if all `questionList` items are permanently linked to `qData` array!
What is wrong?

Comment: *"It is as if all questionList items are permanently linked to qData array!"* Well, yes. You're assigning `qData` to each `curQuestion` member of the `quetsionList`

Comment: And FYI, `qData` isn't an Array.

Comment: `qData` is an object, so it is passed as a reference only. You need to create a _new_ object for each question.

Comment: I don't understand why someone downvoted my question! Isn't SO a site where developers share experience and knowlege? Well, downvoters can vote me down to hell, provided I get answers ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your array contains a reference to the object, this is why everything in the array appears to change after each question. It seems you're expecting the object to be cloned when it is pushed to the array, but that is not the case.

Create a new object for each question like so:

```
curQuestion++;
qData = {}; //  <-------------- create a new object
qData.qQuestionText = gel("questionText").value;

qData.qAnswer1 = gel("Answer1").value;
qData.qAnswer2 = gel("Answer2").value;
qData.qAnswer3 = gel("Answer3").value;
qData.qAnswer4 = gel("Answer4").value;

qData.qAnswerText = gel("AnswerText").value;
questionList[curQuestion] = qData;
```